# ExecCommand on div in Dart M8

Tags: dart, rich-text-editor, dart-html

As of Dart M8 the `Element.document` field has been removed. In a rich editor (as in [Chris Buckett's editor example](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/12/rich-text-editing-in-dart-simple-ui.html)) we used to do the following for changing the weight of some text to bold:

```dart
var el = query("#editme");
el.contentEditable = "true";
el.document.execCommand("bold",true,"");
```

How do you call `execCommand` on a element with the `contenteditable` attribute set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.document was renamed to [Node.ownerDocument](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Node.html#ownerDocument)

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this?